# How can I request the user of my iPhone app to submit a review about the application?

Tags: iphone

I have done with my app. it's a game. now user starts to play,n when he played game for 3 times I want to request that particular user to review this app which is in In-app-purchase. This will increase rankings and downloads of my app.
So how can I do this?

Comment: It will also annoy your user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)

I'm using it in my apps.
You can define when the app will ask the user to rate

Answer (score 1):

**Its for the condition that how many times you play the game**

I have done this function in my app, you just store the status of the app in `NSUserDefault` like one time play 2,3 times play just store the status and at the beginning of the game every time check the condition of the value stored in NSUserDefault if the counter(`NSUserDefault` value) is greater than 3 than call the delegates of InApp Purchase and go ahead best luck.

You can do like:-

```
NSInteger counter=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"value"];
if (counter)
{
    counter=counter + 1; // counter ++
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:counter forKey:@"value"];
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:1 forKey:@"value"];
}
// At the beginning of the game check the condition.
if (counter > 3)
{
    // Call InApp Purchase
}
```